# How can i use provider with map so that each widget is listening to different key in that map?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

is there any way i can use Map object with provider package so that each widget is listening different key in that map and widget should rebuild only when the key which the widget is listening to changes?
I tried using flow_map package but did not help

Comment: See https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector-class.html

Comment: @RémiRousselet thanks a lot for the response, i wanted to ask how can i use the same on a map object
below is my scenario

consider i have a 
`Map<String,int> map = new Map<String,int>();
map.addAll({"a":1});
map.addAll({"b":2});

addToMap(){      //function which adds 1 each time
values["a"] = values["a"]+1;
notifyListners();
}`

what i want is if a widget is listening to values["b"] it should not get rebuilt when values['a'] changes.

i saw the example that you mentioned above but couldnt understand much,appreciate you help